# JQuery Validate Rule not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Fixed - see below :)

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin and for some reason I can't get it to return a valid field - always returns invalid.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryvalidate

Here's what I have

```
        $(function(){
            $("#address").validate({
                valid: function(val){
                    $.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+ escape(val) +"&key=ABQIAAAAnfs7bKE82qgb3Zc2YyS-oBT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxSySz_REpPq-4WZA27OwgbtyR3VcA&sensor=false&output=json&callback=?",
                    function(data, textStatus)
                    {
                        if(data.Status.code=='200')
                        {
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                },
                errorMessage: function(val){
                    return "must geo code";
                },
                appendCompletionIcon: true
            });
        });
```

I can see the GEO code requests coming back as found or not found for any particular address but the validation still fails - if I amend the function as follows I do get an alert yes or alert no in relation to a valid or invalid address but the validation still fails.

```
                    function(data, textStatus)
                    {
                        if(data.Status.code=='200')
                        {
                            alert('yes');
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            alert('no');
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Any help would be appreciated

---

I found a way to hack around this, it's not extremely pretty as it takes two geo code calls to complete. Good enough for my purposes though.

```
var geocode = false;
function geoadd()
{
    $.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+ $("#address").val() +"&key=ABQIAAAAnfs7bKE82qgb3Zc2YyS-oBT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxSySz_REpPq-4WZA27OwgbtyR3VcA&sensor=false&output=json&callback=?",
    function(data, textStatus)
    {
        if(data.Status.code=='200')
        {
            geocode = true;
        }else{
            geocode = false;
        }
    });
}

        $(function(){
            $("#address").validate({
                valid: function(val){
                    geoadd();
                    return geocode;
                },
                errorMessage: function(val){
                    return "must not be blank";
                },
                appendCompletionIcon: true
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation fails regardless of ajax call status because the value returned from your `valid` handler is null, not true or false.

The true or false values are returned by the complete handler of the ajax which is not the same as returning true/false value from your `valid` function.

To solve this issue you would have to either make a synchronous ajax call (I wouldn't recommend it since it locks-up user interface while waiting for the response) or change your validation plugin for some other that supports validation using ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you think I could hack it as I have 50+ fields. Maybe use a function to set a hidden form field with the value 1 or 0 depending on the geo code result and validate against that? Or will I still be wasting my time. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that could work. Trigger your ajax call for geo code checking, then in the ajax response handler do whatever you need (mark #address field as valid or invalid based on the response).